# Google Custom Search JSON API date filter not returning expected results?

Tags: python, json, google-search-api

I have been using Google's Custom Search JSON API to perform higher education research for a while, but have recently ran into some issues with using "exactTerms" and "dateRestrict" parameters (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse.siterestrict/list).

My first question is: Should I expect the same results from the API as I should from using Google's advanced search in my browser?
For example, when I search "University of Utah tuition cost" in-browser, I get the same results as when I run the HTTP request "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=MY_PROGRAMMABLE_SEARCH_ENGINE&q=university%20of%20utah%20tuition%20cost"

When I search ""University of Utah tuition cost""  (double-quotes to imply exact word or phrase search) in-browser, I get the same or very similar results as when I run the request "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=MY_PROGRAMMABLE_SEARCH_ENGIN&exactTerms=university%20of%20utah%20tuition%20cost"

However, when I combine a search with a date filter (under tools, selecting "past year" or "past month" etc.), I do not get the same results as when I run "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=MY_PROGRAMMABLE_SEARCH_ENGINE&exactTerms=university%20of%20utah%20tuition%20cost&dateRestrict=y[1]". A browser search gives 0 results, however, my API search gives at least 10 results.

Is my date filter even working? Should I expect the same (or similar) results to a normal Google browser search?

Thank you!